# Responsive sidebar won't close when I click a link

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have built a sidebar using query, html and css. when the sidebar is activated and overlay appears over the rest of the content and scrolling is prevented using overflow: hidden. Basically, when I click on a link in the sidebar and am redirected, when I click back the side nav is still active/visible, i would like the sidebar to disappear when i click a like or click anywhere on the screen. Please can someone help with this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$menuTrigger = $(".menu-trigger");
$sideNav = $(".side-nav");

$menuTrigger.click(function() {
$(this).toggleClass("active");
$(".content").toggleClass("overlay");
$("body").toggleClass("body-fixed");
$sideNav.toggleClass("slide-out");
});
});

<!-- SIDE NAV -->
<nav class="side-nav">
<div class="side-nav-inner">
 <ul class="main-menu">
   <li class="menu-item">
     <a href="">Home</a>
   </li>
   <li class="menu-item">
     <a href="">About Us</a>
   </li>
   <li class="menu-item">
     <a href="">Rooms</a>
   </li>
   <li class="menu-item">
     <a href="">Contact Us</a>
   </li>
   <li class="menu-item">
     <a href="">Book Now</a>
   </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Show your CSS please.

Comment: Where do you use the class `menu-trigger`?

Comment: the menu-trigger class is a hamburger icon in the header

Answer (score 0):

From the sounds of what you are asking, you want the overlay and sidebar to close so it's not visible when the visitor clicks their browser's back button.

If that is the case, you will need to capture the click on your link, hide your overlay/sidebar **then** redirect the user to the URL.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on("click",".menu-item a",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".content").toggleClass("overlay");
    $("body").toggleClass("body-fixed");
    $sideNav.toggleClass("slide-out");
    location.href = this.href;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I entirely understand your question, and it's hard to give a clear answer when the full code is not provided, BUT - it sounds like the following things are what you want to have happen:

1. When a user clicks on the .menu-trigger, you want it to consistently open/close the sidebar.
2. When a user clicks on a link from within the menu, you want to the sidebar to close.
3. You don't want a user clicking on the sidebar itself, or items that aren't links to close the sidebar inside of the sidebar.
4. You want the user to be able to click anywhere outside of the sidebar to close the sidebar.
5. You want URL redirects to close the sidebar/cleanup.

For #1, it seems like you have this part under control with the above snippet of code you included.

For #2, #3, #4 you will need to set up an event listener on the document itself, so you can capture all clicks.  Anything that doesn't meet your criteria for closing the sidebar should be accounted for.  I'd probably suggest mouseup event, so you could have a conditional to check for something along these lines:

```
    $( document ).mouseup( function( e ) {
        if (
            // Not menu trigger.
            ! $menuTrigger.is( e.target ) &&

            // Not sidenav.
            ! $sideNav.is( e.target ) &&

            // Toplevel items.
            ( ! $( '.menu-item' ).is( e.target ) || $sideNav.has( e.target ).length === 0 ) &&

            // Only when menu is closed.
            $menuTrigger.hasClass( 'active' )
        ) {
            // Handle close of sidebar.
        }
    } );
```

For #5 - you can listen for unload or beforeunload events to trigger closing the menu when the document or child resources are unloaded, with something like this:

```
    $( window ).bind( 'beforeunload unload', function() {
        // Close open sidebars before navigating away.
    } );
```

Taking all of these items above along with your initial code, Here's an example:

```js
$( document ).ready( function() {
 var $menuTrigger = $( ".menu-trigger" ),
  $sideNav = $( ".side-nav" ),
  toggleSidebar = function() {
   console.log( 'clicked' );
   $menuTrigger.toggleClass( "active" );
   $( ".content" ).toggleClass( "overlay" );
   $( "body" ).toggleClass( "body-fixed" );
   $sideNav.toggleClass( "slide-out" );
  };
 
 $menuTrigger.click( () => toggleSidebar() );

 // Listen for outside clicks.
 $( document ).mouseup( function( e ) {
  if (
   // Not menu trigger.
   ! $menuTrigger.is( e.target ) &&
   // Not sidenav.
   ! $sideNav.is( e.target ) &&
   // Only toplevel items.
   ( ! $( '.menu-item' ).is( e.target ) || $sideNav.has( e.target ).length === 0 ) &&
   // Only when menu is closed.
   $menuTrigger.hasClass( 'active' )
  ) {
   // Toggle sidebar.
   toggleSidebar();
  }
 } );

 // Listen for unload before redirected to close menu.
 $( window ).bind( 'beforeunload unload', function() {

  // Check if sidebar is open.
  if ( $menuTrigger.hasClass( 'active' ) ) {

   // Toggle sidebar.
   toggleSidebar();
  }
 } );
} );
```

```css
a {
  color: orange !important;
}

.active {
  background:red;
}

.side-nav {
  background:blue;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.side-nav {
  display: none;
  padding: 1em;
}

.menu-trigger.active + .side-nav {
  display: block;
}

.main-menu {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="menu-trigger">menu trigger</button>
<!-- SIDE NAV -->
<nav class="side-nav">
<div class="side-nav-inner">
 <ul class="main-menu">
   <li class="menu-item">
     <a href="#">Home</a>
   </li>
   <li class="menu-item">
     <a href="#">About Us</a>
   </li>
   <li class="menu-item">
     <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
   </li>
   <li class="menu-item">
     <a href="#">Book Now</a>
   </li>
 </ul>
```

This should help get you going in the right direction.  I'm not sure of the CSS you have in play, but it should provide enough for you to work with and understand the concepts.

Comment: Thank you, this is good however it doesn't allow me to still toggle the menu-trigger hamburger/close button. also if possible I only want the side nav to close when you click either the close button or somewhere other than the sidebar. i appreciate that my original question wasn't clear.

Comment: to clarify i would like for the sidebar to have disappeared when you click back and for the sidebar to disappear when you either click the cross button or an area of the screen other than the sidenav if this is possible. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure we're looking at the same thing, but I removed the external link to codepen, and added the HTML/CSS/JS example inline above in the answer.  The answer still makes use of the code snippet you provided in JS, since that event for the menu-trigger toggle still needs to happen.  Try clicking the "Run Code Snippet" button above to see if that gets you closer to where you need to be.